# Calculate width of div to make equal

Tags: html, css

I have a `form` and number of divs below it:

[image]

Is it possible to automatically calculate the width of the divs so that the last one in a row is running parallel with the submit button? Here's what I mean:

[image]

As you can see from the vertical red line, the div (*aka the black rectangle*) ends exactly where the submit button ends.

Here's a JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/hphmmvuo/

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
  <form method="post" style="margin-left: 0.7%; margin-bottom: 10px;">
    <input class="comment" type="text">
    <input class="commentsubmit" type="submit">
  </form>
  <div class="box inventory">
  </div>
  <div class="box inventory">
  </div>
  <div class="box inventory">
  </div>
  <div class="box inventory">
  </div>
  <div class="box inventory">
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container {
  margin-left: 5%;
  margin-right: 5%;
}

.comment {
  width: 80%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin-right: 0.6%;
}

.commentsubmit {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 14%;
}

.box {
  width: calc(90% / 5);
  display: inline-block;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  margin: 0.7%;
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

Comment: would flexbox be an anwser to you https://jsfiddle.net/hphmmvuo/1/ ?

Comment: any feed back would be welcome, beside can you clarify: is there a single line or can it be several lines with random numbers of inventory boxes ?

Comment: @GCyrillus Brilliant, I really appreciate that! Please post as and I'll mark it as the answer to this question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my comment: https://jsfiddle.net/hphmmvuo/1/

the use of flex does makes it easier.

```css
.container {
  margin-left: 5%;
  margin-right: 5%;
  display:flex;
  /* allow wrapping */
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  /* spray element from a border to another */
  justify-content:space-between;
}    .container:after {
  flex:1;/* extra element will fill up the end of the line*/ 
  content:'';
}
form {
  width:100%;
  display:flex;
}
.comment {
  flex:1;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin-right: 0.6%;
  margin-left:0.7vw;
}

.commentsubmit {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 14%;
}

.box {
  width: calc(90% / 5);
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  margin: 0.7vw 0 0.7vw 1.4vw ;
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <form method="post" style="margin-left: 0.7%; margin-bottom: 10px;">
    <input class="comment" type="text">
    <input class="commentsubmit" type="submit">
  </form>
  <div class="box inventory">
  </div>
  <div class="box inventory">
  </div>
  <div class="box inventory">
  </div>
  <div class="box inventory">
  </div>
  <div class="box inventory">
  </div>
  <div class="box inventory">
  </div>
  <div class="box inventory">
  </div>
  <div class="box inventory">
  </div>
  <div class="box inventory">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Just out of interest, would you mind explaining why the last two divs have a dis-equal margin to the rest? https://jsfiddle.net/5dga2xqc/ http://prntscr.com/b7hewo

Comment: @TheCodesee the pseudo of .container:after fills that space

Comment: Is it possible to amend it so that all the margins are equal?

Comment: yes , remove the css `.container:after {
  flex:1;/* extra element will fill up the end of the line*/ 
  content:'';
}` i added a second snippet without this bit of css

Comment: I apologize if I didn't explain it clearly, sorry. I meant for the margin to be the same as the top, so it would look like this: http://prntscr.com/b7hih0

Comment: i see, you need then to use vw values on margins , snippet updated :)

Comment: I was hoping for them to be next to each other, without one floated to the right

Comment: onop unfortunately it won't space in between is space avalaible divided by numbers of element on the row and then dispatch in betwween

Answer (score 2):

Using `flexbox`, with an added `<div>` around the second line:

https://jsfiddle.net/C14L/ga0766jx/2/

```
.container > div {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  width: 95.9%;
}
.container > div > .box {
  flex: 1 0;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  margin: 0.7%;
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

To have the boxes wrap after a certain number, give them an approximate width. In the example below its after `4` boxes, simply change that number to `7` if you want to wrap after seven boxes.

https://jsfiddle.net/C14L/ga0766jx/3/

```
.container > div {
  ...
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}
.container > div > .box {
  ...
  min-width: calc(90% / 4);
  max-width: calc(100% / 4);
}
```

Comment: Hi and sorry for the late response. Say after 7 boxes, how would I make them go onto the next line?

Comment: I added it to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap your elements to container with the same width. i.e. textbox and submit button to one div, all other divs to another div.